# Customized Mesh with blender python

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I'm interested in creating a plane with a customized mesh from a python script. Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Yes, there are several ways, but you've asked a very general question.  Can you make your question more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way to do this is demonstrated by this code:

```
import bpy
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# How to create a mesh from data.

verts = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
faces = [(0, 1, 2)]

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('aMesh')
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
mesh.update()

object = bpy.data.objects.new('anObject', mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)
```

I have set `verts`, `edges`, and `faces` from hard wired arrays to create a triangle shape with a single face. you would replace that with Python code to generate the arrays to your needs:

- `verts` is an array of 3-tuples. Each tuple is the coordinates of a single vertex in (x, y, z) form.  Although I've used ints, these are usually floating point values.
- `edges` is an array of 2-tuples.  Each tuple lists the position of two vertices in the `verts` array. They will be the two end points of the edge. These are ints.
- `faces` is an array of mixed length tuples.  The numbers are again the positions of vertices in the `verts` array.

calling `from_pydata` will populate the mesh from the three arrays.  There will be one vertex for each entry in `verts`; one edge for each entry in `edges`; and one face for each entry in `faces`.

Once you have the mesh you need to make it the mesh data for an object and then add the object to a collection.